# How to share clipboard between BlueStacks & host Windows PC?

Tags: bluestacks, copy-paste

I want to paste texts copied from host Windows PC to apps inside BlueStacks & vice versa. How to do this?

I am running BlueStacks beta-1...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today, I installed Clipper Plus in BlueStacks and I noticed that its already storing clips I copied in Windows. I have also tried to copy a text in BlueStacks and paste in Windows. It has confirmed that **clipboard has already been shared between BlueStacks & Windows**. Great...

Either this feature has been pushed recently or I didn't notice it without Clipper Plus. I tried to paste using `Ctrl+V` in BlueStacks which still doesn't work. Do paste with proper method: Long-click & choose Paste from menu.

Comment: `Do paste with proper method: Long-click & choose Paste from menu` That's all to it. Well I am shocked :D Thanks

Comment: This option does not work for me on Windows 11 and BlueStack 5. When I copy text into the clipboard on Windows 11, long-click & paste does not insert anything on BlueStack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work with BlueStacks specifically, but whenever I want to share a clipboard between my PC and Android device, I use [AirDroid](http://airdroid.com/).

Comment: Physically, I am on same device, so I'd like to do `Ctrl+C` & `Ctrl+V`..

Comment: When it comes to `AirDroid`, how are you really going to connect these two devices?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Evernote to write and exchange stuff between any two devices, including PC and BlueStacks.