# Bluestack - Can't login to game as keyboard doesn't show

Tags: keyboard, bluestacks

In BlueStacks I'm trying to login to 8 Ball Pool (by Miniclip) but there's no way to type. The android keyboard doesn't show and my pc keyboard is not working at that point of the login.

How can I log into this game?

Comment: I don't use this emulator but you might try to copy and paste login from host: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32329/how-to-share-clipboard-between-bluestacks-host-windows-pc

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! This question should rather be directed at the developer(s) of the game, as they are more likely to know the solution.

Comment: Try opening the IME selector (when you select a text field, the keyboard notification) and toggle "hardware."

Answer (score 1):

In BlueStacks Settings, go to IME settings then click OnScreen Keyboard. Go back to 8 Ball Pool (Or any Miniclip game) and when you click Email or Password to log in the OnScreen Keyboard will now show. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After a restart, the language setting default keyboard was turned on while it needs to be turned off. Once I turned it off the regular android keyboard was back.